# Array value is 0

Tags: arrays, pine-script

i'm trying to build an exit-strategy by using values of buy-alert candle.

```
global_l = array.new_float(2,0)

...code to generate longSingnal ...

if (longSignal) 
    sll = low
    tpl = close + ((close - low) * 2) 
    array.set(global_l, 0, sll)
    array.set(global_l, 1, tpl)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long) //, comment="Buy") //, when=longSignal)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    sl = array.get(global_l,0)
    tp = array.get(global_l,1)
    strategy.exit("SL/TP", stop=sl , limit=tp)
```

well, on the "longSignal" candle i'm getting correct array values. the candle after buy my array values are both 0. tested with label-bar.

where is my fault ? .. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

A variable is re-initialized at every bar, unless you use the `var` prefix. With a `var` prefix, your variable is initialized only once, on the first bar, and keeps it's state throughout the script.

Excerpt from [Expressions, declarations and statements](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#):
*The var keyword is a special modifier that instructs the compiler to create and initialize the variable only once. This behavior is very useful in cases where a variable’s value must persist through the iterations of a script across successive bars.*

Try this:

```
var global_l = array.new_float(2,0)

...code to generate longSingnal ...

if (longSignal) 
    sll = low
    tpl = close + ((close - low) * 2) 
    array.set(global_l, 0, sll)
    array.set(global_l, 1, tpl)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long) //, comment="Buy") //, when=longSignal)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    sl = array.get(global_l,0)
    tp = array.get(global_l,1)
    strategy.exit("SL/TP", stop=sl , limit=tp)
```

Comment: thank you very much !!!

what a simple word can change. so bad from me not seeing this. 

Tested and now it's working to hold the values at array until overriding for next long.